# return keyword functionality in for loop

Tags: java

This is a program to reverse a sentence.
 what is being done by the both "return" keyword in the below code.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class RevSentenceWithoutSplit2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter your sentence");
    String str=sc.nextLine();
    RevSentenceWithoutSplit2 r=new RevSentenceWithoutSplit2();
    System.out.println(r.action(str));
    }
    public String action(String str){
    char ch[]=str.toCharArray();
    String result="";
    for (int i =0; i <str.length() ; i++){
        if(ch[i]==' '){
            return action(str.substring(i+1))+str.substring(0,i)+" ";
        }
    }
    return str+ " ";
     }
 }
```

Comment: so whats is the question?Do you want to get this method included in Java API?

Comment: Do want to know how return statement works in general or particularly in your program?

Comment: The same thing `return` always does.

Comment: @Imran in this program

Comment: Are you trying to reverse a String? Is that the question?

Comment: @BrunoFranco i want to know what is being done by two "return" Statement used in this program

Comment: @KumarAbhinav i want to understand the flow of return statement with respect to this porgram

Comment: @khwaish You can have many return statements.The method returns to the caller method once it encounters a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's a recursive function, so it calls itself.

It takes the first word (the chars until it finds a space) and then it appends the rest of the sentence to the front of it, in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

This action method is working in a recursive way.

If it finds a space character (`ch[i] == ' '`), it will get a substring with one more character (`str.substring(i + 1)`) appended with the beggining of the string (`str.substring(0, i`)), and pass this new string to the action method again and again.

It will happen until it reads all the entered string spaces.